# How to optimize this computation

Tags: optimization, formula, floating-accuracy

I'm writing a model-checker which relies on the computation of a coefficient which is used intensively by the algorithms which is the following:

![alt text][1]

where `q` is double, `t` a double too and `k` an int. `e` stands for exponential function. This coefficient is used in steps in which `q` and `t` don't change while `k` always starts from 0 until the sum of all previous coefficients (of that step) reaches 1.

My first implementation was a literal one:

```
let rec fact k =
  match k with
    0 | 1 -> 1
    | n -> n * (fact (k - 1))

let coeff q t k = exp(-. q *. t) *. ((q *. t) ** (float k)) /. float (fact k)
```

Of course this didn't last so much since computing the whole factorial was just unfeasible when `k` went over a small threshold (15-20): obviously results started to go crazy. So I rearranged the whole thing by doing incremental divisions:

```
let rec div_by_fact v d =
  match d with
    1. | 0. -> v
    | d -> div_by_fact (v /. d) (d -. 1.)

let coeff q t k = div_by_fact (exp(-. q *. t) *. ((q *. t) ** (float k))) (float k)
```

This version works quite well when `q` and `t` are enough 'normal' but when things gets strange, eg `q = 50.0` and `t = 100.0` and I start to calculate it from `k = 0 to 100` what I get is a series of 0s followed by NaNs from a certain number until the end.

Of course this is caused by operations with numbers that start to get too near to 0 or similar problems.

Do you have any idea in how I can optimize the formula to be able to give enough accurate results over a wide spread of inputs?

Everything should be already 64 bit (since I'm using OCaml which uses doubles by default). Maybe there is a way to use 128 bit doubles too but I don't know how.

I'm using OCaml but you can provide ideas in whatever language you want: C, C++, Java, etc. I quite used all of them.

Comment: what about taking  `log` + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: sum(k=0,...)x^k/k! == exp(x), so it almost looks like you are doing exp(-qt)*exp(qt) = 1. Or am I missing something? Note that if qt is large you can make use of exp(qt) = exp(qt/2)^2, i.e. you can divide qt by 2 enough times to make the series short, and then square it that number of times to get the desired answer. Not sure if that is useful for what you're doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
qt^k/k! = e^[log[qt^k/k!]]
log[qt^k/k!] = log[qt^k] - log[k!] // log[k!] ~ klnk - k  by stirling
             ~ k ln(qt) - (k lnk - k)
             ~ k ln(qt/k) - k
```

for small values of k, Stirling approximation is not accurate.
however, since you appear to be doing finite known range, you can compute `log[k!]`and put it in array, avoiding any errors whatsoever.

of course there are multiple variations you can do further.

Comment: I tried analitic apporach like you suggested, but still haven't managed to obtain similar results.. I'll keep trying! In the meanwhile I decomposed the operation to keep within bounds floats.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (I believe), but pehaps just a clarification .If I misunderstood something, I'll delete it after your comment.

As I understand, you are trying to calculate n, such as the following  sum is equal to 1.

[image]

As you may see it approaches to 1 asymptotically, it'll never be EQUAL to 1.
Please correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes you are right, I used equal but I meant enough near to 1.0. What I actually do is to choose an error like for example `e = 1e-6` so that `sum > 1 - e`..